# Регулярные выражения / подстановка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

пишу типа маску... маска выглядит так `(n1)-(n2)`
нужно сделать следующее: при вводе в поле, например: 12, должна превращаться в такое - `(1)-(2)` (сразу же), или если ввели 56, то `(5)-(6)`... я понимаю, что можно сделать так: `.replace(/(\d)(\d)/, "($1)-($2)");`... но проблема в том, что это все дело заменятся только после окончания ввода всех указанных символов в регэкспе... нужно так, например, ввели 3, заменяется на `(3)-`, ввели еще 4, заменяется все на `(3)-(4)`... то есть все на лету, как сделать?

Comment: Регулярные выражения здесь не нужны. Задействуйте следующие технологии:  обработка событий ввода от пользователя; условный оператор; сложение строк.

Answer (score 1):

Тут дело не в маске,а в обработчике события. Повесьтесь на keyup,и учтите то,что часть введенных данных уже обработана регуляркой

Answer (score -1):

Используйте событие `input`, оно возникает сразу при вводе (в отличие от `change`).

```js
let test   = document.getElementById('test'),
    result = document.getElementById('result');
    
test.addEventListener('input', () => {
  let matches = test.value.match(/\d/g);
  if (!matches) {
    result.textContent = '';
    return;
  }
  if (matches.length > 1)
    result.textContent = '(' + matches.join(')-(') + ')';
  else
    result.textContent = '(' + matches[0] + ')';
});
```

```css
#test,
#result {
  font: 18px sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<input id='test'>
<br>
<span id='result'>
```

Упс... некропост :)

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, маска нужна **внутри** Input

Answer (score -1):

Люди, используйте современные технологии, типа реактивного программирования. Уходите от программирования на уровне слежения за событиями.

```js
"use strict";
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#test-form",
  data: {
    input: "12"
  },
  computed: {
    result: function(){
      return this.input.replace(/(\d)(\d)/, "($1)-($2)");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="test-form">
  <input type="text" v-model="input">
  <div>Вы ввели: {{input}}</div>
  <div>Вычислили: {{result}}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: реактивное программирование не такая уж и современная технология